# How to use an intermediate table to lookup values using $lookup pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have three classes: Parent - Intermediate - Child. All relationships are '1:m'.
The task is: for each parent get the sum of all its children with a condition.

Here is the code:

```
'use strict';
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let TestParentSchema = new Schema({
  Name: { type: String },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('TestParent', TestParentSchema);

'use strict';
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let TestIntermediateSchema = new Schema({
  Name: { type: String },
  Parent: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'TestParent' },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('TestIntermediate', TestIntermediateSchema);

'use strict';
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let TestChildSchema = new Schema({
  Name: { type: String },
  Value: { type: Number, required: true },
  Intermediate: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'TestIntermediate' },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('TestChild', TestChildSchema);
```

Populate it as follows:

```
  let parent1 = new TestParent({ Name: 'parent1' });
  let parent2 = new TestParent({ Name: 'parent2' });
  parent1.save();
  parent2.save();

  let inter11 = new TestIntermediate({ Name: 'inter1-1', Parent: parent1 });
  let inter21 = new TestIntermediate({ Name: 'inter2-1', Parent: parent2 });
  inter11.save();
  inter21.save();

  let child111 = new TestChild({ Name: 'child1-1-1', Intermediate: inter11, Value: 5 });
  let child112 = new TestChild({ Name: 'child1-1-2', Intermediate: inter11, Value: 60 });
  let child211 = new TestChild({ Name: 'child2-1-1', Intermediate: inter21, Value: 10 });
  let child212 = new TestChild({ Name: 'child2-1-2', Intermediate: inter21, Value: 70 });

  child111.save();
  child112.save();
  child211.save();
  child212.save();
```

The goal is to get for each parent sum of children with Value<50. ('5' for 'parent1' and '10' for 'parent2')

To begin let's get values of all children:

```
TestParent.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'testintermediates',
          localField: '_id',
          foreignField: 'Parent',
          as: 'myIntermediates',
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'testchildren',
          localField: 'myIntermediates._id',
          foreignField: 'Intermediate',
          as: 'myChildren',
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          myName: '$Name',
          sumChildren: { $sum: '$myChildren.Value' },
        },
      },
    ],
    function(err, results) {
      let res1 = results[0].sumChildren === 5;
      let res2 = results[1].sumChildren === 10;
    }
  );
```

Ok.

Now let's try to add a condition to the second lookup:

```
TestParent.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'testintermediates',
          localField: '_id',
          foreignField: 'Parent',
          as: 'myIntermediates',
        },
      },
      // {
      //   $lookup: {
      //     from: 'testchildren',
      //     localField: 'myIntermediates._id',
      //     foreignField: 'Intermediate',
      //     as: 'myChildren',
      //   },
      // },
      // { //to check if this approach works with the first level (it works)
      //   $lookup: {
      //     from: 'testintermediates',
      //     let: { myid: '$_id' },
      //     pipeline: [
      //       {
      //         $match:
      //         {
      //           $expr: {
      //             $eq: ['$Parent', '$$myid'],
      //             // $eq: ['$LocalId', 55],

      //           },
      //         },
      //       },
      //     ],
      //     as: 'myIntermediates',
      //   },
      // },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'testchildren',
          let: { intermedId: '$myIntermediates._id' },
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match:
              {
                $expr: {
                   $eq: ['$Intermediate', '$$intermedId'], //it doesn't work (
                  // $eq: ['$Value', 60], //it works
                },
              },
            },
          ],
          as: 'myChildren',
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          myName: '$Name',
          sumChildren: { $sum: '$myChildren.Value' },
        },
      },
    ],
    function(err, results) {
      let res1 = results[0].sumChildren === 5;
      let res2 = results[1].sumChildren === 10;
    }
  );
```

For now, I solved this task by using '$unwind' with '$group' but wondering if there is a way to just add a condition to a pipeline. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> wondering if there is a way to just add a condition to a pipeline

First, let's break this down from the first stage of the pipeline. The first `$lookup` stage:

```
    "$lookup": {
      from: "testintermediates",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "Parent",
      as: "myIntermediates"}
```

Returns an array of matching intermediates as `myIntermediates`. For example:

```
    {"_id": 1, 
     "x": "some value",
     "myIntermediates": [
         { "_id": 1, "Parent": 1, "y": 5 },
         { "_id": 2, "Parent": 1, "y": 7 },
         { "_id": 3, "Parent": 1, "y": 2 }
     ]}
```

When you chain the second `$lookup` stage using another [single equality match syntax of $lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#equality-match):

```
    "$lookup": {
      from: "testchildren", 
      localField: "myIntermediates._id",
      foreignField: "Intermediate",
      as: "myChildren"}
```

This works because when the `localField` is an array, the equality condition between the `localField` and `foreignField` is treated as:

```
"foreignField": { "$in": [ "localField.elem1", "localField.elem2", ... ] }
```

So if you use [$in expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/#exp._S_in) as well in the second `$lookup` stage of [uncorrelated subqueries $lookup syntax](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) it should work as well. 
The reason using `$eq` doesn't work is because an equality comparison between a single value with an array of value would not be true.

To sum up, your aggregation query can be written as:

```
TestParent.aggregate(
    [
      {"$lookup": {
          from: "testintermediates",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "Parent",
          as: "myIntermediates",
        },
      },
      {"$lookup": {
          from: "testchildren",
          let: { "intermedId": "$myIntermediates._id" },
          pipeline: [
            {"$match":
              {"$expr": {
                   "$in": ["$Intermediate", "$$intermedId"],
                },
              },
            },
          ],
          as: "myChildren",
        },
      },
      {"$project": {
          myName: "$Name",
          sumChildren: { "$sum": "$myChildren.Value" },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

See also [Specify Multiple Join Conditions with $lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins)